# Executing multiple instances of a Runnable on separate threads crashes my app without log

Tags: android, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, executor

What am I doing wrong?
The below code crashes during the second loop when the 2nd thread is created.
I have tried AsyncTask, Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor .... but still crashes.

What I want to be achieved is to run instances of the runnable on separate threads parallelly so as to take advantage of the other processor cores and ram. The code runs well sequentially.

```
if (!listOfSubLists.isEmpty()) {
  for (final List<String> subList : listOfSubLists) {
    if (!subList.isEmpty()) {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          int sc1 = 0; //int count = arFPSubAppIDs.length;
          for (String appID : subList) {
            FingerPrint fingerPrint = mDBHelper.fetchFingerPrint(appID, FingerPrint.RIGHT_INDEX);
            if (fingerPrint != null) {
              List<String> alFingerData = fingerPrint.getFingerData();
              for (String encodedFPData : alFingerData) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(encodedFPData)) {
                  int sc2;
                  byte[] fpDataB = Base64.decode(encodedFPData, Base64.DEFAULT);
                  sc2 = FPMatch.getInstance().MatchFingerData(mRefData, fpDataB);
                  if (sc2 > sc1) {
                    sc1 = sc2;
                  }

                }
              }

              if (sc1 >= TEMPLATE_MATCHING_THRESHOLD) {
                //Match found ...
                //all tasks completed
                final long diff = /*System.currentTimeMillis()*/System.nanoTime()-startTime1;

                final int finalSc = sc1;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                    tvStatus4.setText(String.format("Time:%s, Score:%s", String.valueOf(diff),String.valueOf(finalSc)));
                    Toast.makeText(BluetoothReader2.this, "Template Matched!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    closeProgressDialog();
                  }
                });

                //mFPHandler.obtainMessage(sc1).sendToTarget();
                /*Message msg = mFPHandler.obtainMessage(TEMPLATE_MATCHED_MESSAGE); //set what message ...
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt(TEMPLATE_MATCHING_SCORE, sc1);
                bundle.putString(TEMPLATE_MATCHING_APPID, appID);
                bundle.putString(TEMPLATE_MATCHING_TASKID, mTaskID);
                msg.setData(bundle);
                mFPHandler.sendMessage(msg);*/
              }
            }
          }
          //Task completed....
          mTemplateMatchingMessageTotalCount++;
          if (mTemplateMatchingMessageTotalCount==listCount) {
            //all tasks completed
            final long diff = /*System.currentTimeMillis()*/System.nanoTime()-startTime1;

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                tvStatus4.setText(String.format("Time:%s, ", String.valueOf(diff)));
                Toast.makeText(BluetoothReader2.this, "All Tasks Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                closeProgressDialog();
              }
            });

          }

          //mFPHandler.obtainMessage(sc1).sendToTarget();
          /*Message msg = mFPHandler.obtainMessage(TASK_COMPLETED_MESSAGE); //set what message ...
          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          bundle.putInt(TEMPLATE_MATCHING_SCORE, sc1);
          msg.setData(bundle);
          mFPHandler.sendMessage(msg);*/
        }
      }).start();
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: Share logcat of the Error..

Comment: Add a try catch when invoking the second thread and on catch print the stack-trace which should give you a log output

Comment: logcat is 07-01 02:10:58.981 6383-6513/ng.doit A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x65 in tid 6513 (Thread-13)

Comment: Please, how do I run this code simultaneously on separate background threads?